# How do I need to return the query in order to count the number of rows, and how do I count the rows?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

Basically I am not exactly sure how to fetch the query in order to be able to count the number of rows.

I need the get the number of rows for the purpose of a checker.

Code below:

```
$query = $handler->prepare("SELECT * FROM Admins WHERE ID= :userID OR Username= :userName OR Password= :encPass");
$query->bindParam(':userID', $userID);
$query->bindParam(':userName', $userName);
$query->bindParam(':encPass', $encrypted_password);
$query->execute();
```

some how right here fetch in a way that lets me count the number of rows

```
if (number of rows from query is >=1){
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PDOStatement` object provides a [`rowCount()`](https://devdocs.io/php/pdostatement.rowcount) method, which returns the number of rows `SELECT`ed:

> If the last SQL statement executed by the associated `PDOStatement`
>   was a `SELECT` statement, some databases may return the number of rows
>   returned by that statement. However, this behaviour is not guaranteed
>   for all databases and should not be relied on for portable
>   applications.

Comment: So would I just do $count =  $query->rowCount() and then in the if statement put $count >=1?

Comment: @Austin Essentially, yes! You could also simply go with: `if( $query->rowCount() >= 1 )`

Comment: So this what I have done, https://gyazo.com/de46beac3d0e98ecd7b57714e33feb7f ... Whenever I get to the else statement, the page just goes blank.

Comment: Disregard, I left off a value. Thanks for the help!